# How to uninstall anaconda(python 3.6.4) from windows7? Start menu or control panel or unistaller.exe in prog file(x86) not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to uninstall **Anaconda Navigator** (*python 3.6.4*) from my windows 7. There was no uninstaller shortcut in start menu, so I went like **Control Panel > Programs > Uninstall Python 3.6.4**. But even after this uninstallation, this program left 5GB of data in D:\Program Files(x86)\Anaconda 3(actual path of the installed files).
Then, I found an **uninstaller.exe** in the above path and tried that too. But even after unistallation guide shows that the software is uninstalled successfully, not a single data gets deleted. How will I be able to erase Anaconda and safely go back to the basic Python 2.7(IDLE Mode) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exactly uninstall anaconda(python 3.6.4) from windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50031900/how-to-exactly-uninstall-anacondapython-3-6-4-from-windows-7)