# How to exactly uninstall anaconda(python 3.6.4) from windows 7?

Tags: python

I was trying to uninstall Anaconda Navigator (python 3.6.4) from my windows 7. There was no uninstaller shortcut in start menu, so I went like

```
Control Panel > Programs > Uninstall Python 3.6.4
```

But even after this uninstallation, this program left huge data in `D:\Program Files(x86)\Anaconda 3(actual path of the installed files)`. Then, I found an uninstaller.exe in the above path and tried that too. But even after uninstallation guide shows that the software is uninstalled successfully, not a single data gets deleted. How will I be able to erase Anaconda and safely go back to the basic Python 2.7(IDLE Mode) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337928/how-to-remove-anaconda-from-windows-completely). Have a look at the answer #3

Comment: Maybe the possible duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/q/48236584/7735095 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53272378/which-folders-should-i-remove-after-uninstalling-anaconda-on-windows-10?noredirect=1&lq=1 could be helpful for you too?

Answer (score 0):

One way that worked for me was:

Doing an Explorer search for `Uninstall-Anaconda.exe`, and running it afterwards.