# Which folders should I remove after uninstalling Anaconda on Windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, uninstallation

[Prehistory: I have a lot of bugs in my Anaconda Installation (like Spyder not opening, not being able to install certain packages and so on). I think this problems occur because I installed it when python 3.7 was very new and not compatible with other stuff.]

Therefore I uninstalled Anaconda from Windows 10 using

- `Uninstall-Anaconda.exe` in `C:\Users\username\Anaconda3`

like suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/39490516/7735095.

After doing so I fave found out that there would have been a better removal method:

- executing:

  ```
  conda install anaconda-clean
  anaconda-clean
  ```

  BEFORE uninstalling Anaconda,

like suggested in https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/.
But now it is too late for it because I already uninstalled Anaconda the classical way.

So my question is? What should I remove now manually?

For example in `C:\Users\jakob` I still have the folders:

```
.anaconda
.conda
.ipython
.jupyter
.matplotlib
.spyder-py3
```

and the file:

```
.condarc
```

Can I destroy anything when I delete those folders and this file? Why did the default uninstall leave them on my system?

What about:

```
C:\Users\jakob\AppData\Local\conda
C:\Users\jakob\AppData\Local\Spyder

C:\Users\jakob\AppData\Roaming\jupyter
C:\Users\jakob\AppData\Roaming\Jedi

C:\Users\jakob\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\#!001\MicrosoftEdge\User\Default\DOMStore\YP1KVEAM\conda[1].xml
C:\Users\jakob\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\#!121\MicrosoftEdge\User\Default\DOMStore\0KLIGYWH\conda[1].xml
```

Can I delete all of them?

In my registry I still have:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\PythonCore
```

Is it dangerous to delete it from the registry? Why did `Uninstall-Anaconda.exe` leave it on my system?

Do you think there are further traces of Anaconda that could be removed?

Comment: Many of those dot directories contain settings and config for the various packages, and are presumably left there with the idea that you want to keep your own settings around even if the app/package has been removed. Theyre all safe to delete. If you reinstall anaconda/those packages again, the folders will end up being recreated anyway. I'm not sure about the registry key

Comment: @Simon Thank you! I have found more anaconda related files and folders in `C:\Users\jakob\AppData`. So I added them to my question.